# Multiple ablines in xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

I have a "long" dataframe defined as:

```
q <- data.frame(Indicator.Code=factor(),Year=numeric(),Value=numeric())
```

and am trying to plot in a single xyplot the values as a function of the year, for each different `Indicator.Code`, as follows

```
xyplot( Value~Year,data=q,group=Indicator.Code)
```

So far, so good. Now I am trying to add lines corresponding to the linear regressions

```
rlm(q$Value[q$Indicator.Code==a]~q$Year[q$Indicator.Code==a])
```

for all the values of `Indicator.Code`.

I do not know how to do it. The usual way to add regression lines, i.e

```
xyplot( Value~Year,data=q,group=Indicator.Code),
panel = function(x, y) {
  panel.xyplot(x, y)
  panel.abline(rlm(y ~ x))
}))
```

does not work properly (it computes a single regression, and adds a single regression line, for the whole dataset). Besides, I have already computed the regressions (I need them for things other than graphics too), and hate the idea of having to recompute them.

Any hints a novice could follow?

Comment: I think you need a panel.group. If you has used a formula like `Value~Year|Indicator.Code` (without "group=Indicator.Code") it would have given you separate calculation and plots.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a `ggplot2` addict: ). The equivalent in `ggplot2` does what you expect:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(q, aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = Indicator.Code)) + 
   geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "rlm")
```

Note that I believe you pass any function as `method`, but without a reproducible example it is hard to check.

Answer (score 2):

For a customized panel function that plots separate symbols for each `group`, lattice requires that you wrap the actual panel function in a call to `panel.superpose()`.  Here's an example, using data in the `mtcars` data.frame.

```
library(lattice)
library(MASS)

myPanel <- function(x,y,...) {
    panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
    panel.abline(rlm(y~x), ...)
}

xyplot(mpg~disp, group = cyl, data = mtcars,
       panel = function(...) panel.superpose(panel.groups = myPanel, ...))

## Or, equivalently:
xyplot(mpg~disp, group = cyl, data = mtcars, 
       panel = panel.superpose, panel.groups = myPanel)
```

[image]

Comment: @DWin -- Thanks. I love **lattice**, but do sometimes wish it was a bit more user friendly. `panel.superpose()` (and, elsewhere, `subscripts`) always feels like things that "should" be taken care of behind the scenes, without requiring the user to even know about them!

Comment: `<sermon>` In that regard I really love `ggplot2`. A lot of times things just work, and require minimum knowledge of the internal workings of ggplot2. `</sermon>`

Comment: thanks for the answer. works perfectly the only problem i still have is that MyPanel will compute the regression again (i have the regressions computed before creating the graph). thanks again.

Comment: @user2345448 -- That's an interesting question but quite different than what you asked here. I'd suggest asking it as a new separate question, but not until you've constructed a reproducible example that gives folks something concrete to work on. (You might want, for example, to use the `mtcars` data.frame and also include the object in which you've stored slopes and intercepts or fitted models or whatever. Cheers.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- I so much want to love **ggplot2** too, but every time I've tried to pick it up, I've almost immediately gotten frustrated by how hard it is to figure out how things are "actually" working, at the implementation level. The long chains of proto environments and layer upon layer upon layer of indirection **irritate** me, and leave me feeling totally at the mercy of the few developers who really get the system. I think I prefer "**I** can always make it work" to "a lot of times **it** just works" ;) That said, I do know that at *some* point I too will have to join the borg ;)

Comment: @Josh O'Brien Again, thanks for the help. Though it doesn't really matter, the question about recomputing the regression was actually included in my original question. I will rework it as you suggested.

Comment: @user2345448 -- Right you are! Missed that. Going that direction will require a lot more careful book-keeping on your part, as your panel function will need to be always aware of the panel and group that it is currently plotting. In particular, you'll want to use the `panel.number()` function to get the panel, and the value of either the `group.number` or `group.value` variables.

Comment: Those last two appear at the bottom of `panel.superpose`, and are passed on to `panel.xyplot` (or whatever function you supply for `panel.groups`). They don't appear in the definition of `panel.xyplot`, but will be available inside the call to it, having been passed in via the `...`. You will need to use the values of `panel.number()` and, e.g., `group.value` to select the correct fitted model object or abline coefficients from your previously constructed list of them. If you get this working, please do post it, as I'd be interested to see how you did it! Best of luck.